# Server network communication stalls

Tags: networking, sql-server, timeout, windows-sbs-2008

I'm running SBS 2008 as a file server, SQL server, IIS7 Server, and Exchange server, and very recently I am getting some very confusing stalls on it. During these "stalls," file services will cause any program with a file opened on a network drive (say like MS word or Excel) to hang, and report to Windows that the program is no longer responding. HTTP requests to the server will go unanswered and timeout, as will RDP connections. Oddly enough, Exchange via Outlook seems fine during these periods, as does SQL.

Now, the really strange part to me: We run this on a Dell server, and if I try to connect to IDRAC when this happens, those connections time out as well. Eventually, the server will right itself, and everything will be OK for days or even weeks.

The event log is (typically) unhelpful. I'm wondering where I should start to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Seeing as the iDRAC is unrelated to the OS and it's also experiencing the problem I would suggest looking at your network infrastructure.

Comment: That was exactly my thought too, but ping, SQL, and Exchange seem unaffected.

Comment: I moved the server to an alternate switch, and this appeared to help for about a week, but then, last night, the same exact thing happened. All SMB related traffic was stalled for about 5 minutes, while ping, Exchange, and SQL requests went through. Honestly if I could find some type of diagnostic program or equipment to just get an idea of where the failure might be, I'd jump at it.